# return multiple objects with same name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

MultipleObjectsReturned at /user/(name of object)/
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned

Request Method:     GET

Exception Value:    get() returned more than one Canvas -- it returned 2!

Exception Location:     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 389

Multiple objects with the same name, but a user can only have one unique object name.

Whenever I create another object with the same name I get this error (MultipleObjectsReturned). I want to allow every user to create one unique object name.

For example: user1 can have a unique object name of (test) and user2 can also have a unique object name of (test).

```
class Object(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    object_name         = models.CharField(
                        max_length=100,
                        validators=[
                            # validate_canvas_title,
                            RegexValidator(
                                    regex=CANVAS_REGEX,
                                    message='Canvas must only contain Alpahnumeric characters',
                                    code='invalid_canvas_title'
                                )],
                        )
    slug                = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'object_name']
```

view

```
def canvasView(request, username=None, slug=None):
    user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
    object = get_object_or_404(Object, slug__iexact=slug)

    template = "pages/object.html"
    context = {
        'user' : user,
        'object': object,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the user in the query.

```
object = get_object_or_404(Object, user=user, slug__iexact=slug)
```

Comment: How would i get the object through the user. do i user user.object_set.all(), and then filter?

Comment: Yes you could do `user.object_set.get(slug__iexact=slug)`, but then you would have to catch the ObjectNotFound exception and raise 404.

Answer (score 1):

The get_object_or_404 function returns the object, which satisfies the condition specified, the thing to keep in my mind is that there should only be a single object with the specified condition.
It doesn't return a list or anything like that. If multiple objects are found, then it returns the so called error.

You need to pass `user` into the arguments,

```
object_name = get_object_or_404(Object, user=user, slug__iexact=slug)
```

Or you could define a related name constraint in the model, for the user field,

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="my_objects")
```

Then, you can get from the user objects directly,

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
object_name = user.my_objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
```

Also, using python default keywords for naming variables are strictly not recommended. "object" is a valid python keyword. Its just not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Set `unique=True` on the model field `object_name`.

Comment: but if i set it to unique then it won't allow me to have multiple objects with the same name.

Comment: This won't work, because  'user1 can have a unique object name of (test) and user2 can also have a unique object name of (test).' He could use `unique_together = (("user", "object_name"),)`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together